# How to ask for a string, then ask for a position of string, then remove the letter and print the word without the letter

Tags: python, string

**Python**

I want to create a program that asks the user for a string, then asks the user to select a position of the string to be removed, and then print the string without the letter of the position he chose to be removed. I'm struggling to find the correct way to do that.

```
x = input ('Enter a String: ')
sum = 0

if type(x) != str:
    print ('Empty Input')
else:
    y = input ('Enter the position of the string to be removed: ')

for i in range x(start, end):
    print ('New string is: ', x - i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use slice notation, and just leave out the character in the specified position:

```
x = input ('Enter a String: ')
if type(x) != str:
    print ('Empty Input')
else:
    y = int(input('Enter the position of the string to be removed: ')) or 1
    print(x[:y-1] + x[y:])
```

> x = "abcdefgh"
> abcefgh

Comment: If someone enters a position that does not exist, what message should it appear?
Ex. If someone enters the word "apple" and asks for position 10 to be removed?

Comment: I have another question as well. When I ask for position 0, normally it should remove the first letter of the string, because strings start from 0, is that right?
In your example code, by typing the word "hello", it prints "hellhello" instead of "ello".

Comment: Enter a String: hello
Enter the position of the string to be removed: 0
hellhello

Comment: Currently the code will remove no chaarcters if a number greater than the length of `x` is specified. The code assumes the user is entering a 1-indexed number. For 0-indexed, remove the `or 1` and change the logic to `x[:y] + x[y+1:]`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially how you can do this is simply using the .split() method to split it by the index of the string letter and join it with the join() method

```py
x = input ('Enter a String: ')
sum = 0
if type(x) != str:
    print ('Empty Input')
else:
    y = int(input('Enter the position of the string to be removed: '))
x  = ''.join([''.join(x[:y]), ''.join(x[y+1:])])
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [this link](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-remove-characters-from-a-string-by-index/) help?

Excerpt from said page:

```
strObj = "This is a sample string"
index = 5
# Slice string to remove character at index 5
if len(strObj) > index:
    strObj = strObj[0 : index : ] + strObj[index + 1 : :]
```

Comment: What is "srtObj" exaclty? Haven't learnt this yet.

Comment: @Bawzevic: This is just a string in my example. I will adjust the answer so it becomes more apparent.

Comment: Thanks, mate, that really helped!

Comment: I have an extra question to ask.
If the user wants to know, how many of the letters are in the string, how can I code this?
For example, let's say we have the word 'banana'.
Banana has 3 'a', so it should print "The string banana has 3 as."
And then print
"The percentage of as are in this word is 50%."
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would that you make that specific question into a new one, so as to not lose the history of this question. In general though, it's a good idea to check the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html). Furthermore. "Thisismystring".count('i') would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The following part is unnecessary:

```py
if type(x) != str:
    print ('Empty Input')
```

As whatever comes from `input` builtin is always going to be a string.
The modified version of your code:

```py
text = input('Enter a String: ')
if text == '': 
    print('Empty string')
else: 
    pos = int(input('Enter the position of the string to be removed: '))
    print(text[:pos] + text[pos+1:]) # TO remove value at  given index
    print(text[pos+1:]) # TO remove everything bofore the given index
```

**SAMPLE RUN:**

```py
Enter a String: >? helloworld
Enter the position of the string to be removed: >? 4
hellworld
world
```